# Probability - Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> A (random) number $X$ of people in a given year that are bitten by poisonous snakes follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Whenever someone is bitten there is a chance $p_1$ that they make a full recovery, a probability $p_2$ that they survive but become blind, and a probability $p_3$ that they die as a result of the bite – where of course $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1$. We may assume that which of the three outcomes a particular bite victim has is not influenced by what happens to the other victims, or the total number of victims that year, etc. etc.
>   Let $X_1$ denote the number of people that are bitten in the upcoming year and make a full recovery; let $X_2$ denote the number of people that are bitten and become blind; and let $X_3$ denote the number of bite victims that die.
>
> (i) Show that $X_i ∼ \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda p_i)$.
>   (Hint: It suffices that $\mathbb{P}(X_i = k)$ has the required form for each $k$. What is $\mathbb{P}(X_i = k\mid X = n)$?)

Thanks for any hints or help in advance!!!

Comment: Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site to see how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2):

The computation is done only for the index $1$. We use the complementary probability weight $q_1=1-p_1$. 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb P(X_1=k)
&=
\Bbb P(X_1=k\text{ and }X\ge k)
\\
&=
\sum_{N\ge k}\Bbb P(X_1=k\text{ and }X=N)
\\
&=
\sum_{N\ge k}\Bbb P(X=N)\cdot \Bbb P(X_1=k\ |\ X=N)
\\
&=
e^{-\lambda}
\sum_{N\ge k}\frac{\lambda^N}{N!}
\cdot \binom Nk p_1^kq_1^{N-k}
\\
&=
e^{-\lambda}
p_1^k
\sum_{N\ge k}\frac{\lambda^N}{N!}
\cdot \frac {N!}{k!(N-k)!} \cdot q_1^{N-k}
\\
&=
\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
p_1^k
\sum_{N\ge k}\frac{\lambda^N}{(N-k)!} \cdot q_1^{N-k}
\\
&\qquad\text{ Substitution: $M=N-k$, then $N\ge k$ becomes $M\ge 0$,}
\\
&=
\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
p_1^k
\sum_{M\ge 0}\lambda ^k\frac{\lambda^M}{M!} \cdot q_1^{M}
\\
&=
\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
(\lambda p_1)^k
\underbrace{\sum_{M\ge 0}\frac{(q_1\lambda)^M}{M!}}_{=\exp(q_1\lambda)}
\qquad\text{(edited)}\\
&=
\frac{e^{-\lambda(1-q_1)}}{k!}
(\lambda p_1)^k
\\
&=
\frac{e^{-\lambda p_1}}{k!}
(\lambda p_1)^k
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: How did u know what is $ℙ(X1=k | X=N)$ equal to?

Comment: Let us assume that we focus on the part of the big probability space "usually $\Omega$, usually not even mentioned", where $X=N$. So there are exactly $N$ persons who got a bite. The first person has the chance $p_1$ to get full recovery. We draw a "combinatorial tree", a bifurcation, like a $<$, upper hand has probability $p_1$, lower $q_1$. At next step, second person, we put a $<$ at each end, so get first $4$ possible outcomes. But two of them correspond to the event "exactly one person gets full recovery". We draw a big bullet for it. Its probability is $2p_1q_1$. The other end nodes...

Comment: have probabilities $p_1^2$ and $q_1^2$. The obtained tree is a so called recombination tree, since we merged together some nodes. We continue $N$ steps for the $N$ persons. At the $N$.th step we have only the outcomes: $N$ persons got full recovery, $N-1$ persons got full recovery, ... , exactly $k$ persons, ... and each of these final events are obtained by merging together many nodes in the binary tree with $2^N$ final states. Each such node in the binary tree has probability $p_1\times p_1\times\dots\times p_1\times q_1\times q_1\times\dots\times q_1$, where the factors show up in a...

Comment: different order, possibly, but exactly $k$ factors are $p_1$ and exactly $(N-k)$ are $q_1$, the other factors of course. Now there is only one question, how many possibilities are there to pick a collective of $k$ persons, those that will get full recovery at the end. (Each such collective has its chance, the chance is the same, $p_1^k\cdot q_1^{N-k}$.) This is the same as finding the number of subsets with $k$ elements in a given set with $N$ elements. Or as expanding $(x+1)^N$, and isolating the coefficient of $x^k$ in the final. (Thus getting the set of the factors where we pick the $x$...

Comment: inside $x+1$, not the one.) The number is $$\binom Nk$$ each time.

Comment: @projectilemotion: thanks for pointing to the error!